# Mysql: calculating dates without time

Tags: mysql

i have to find out, if a cancellation date is less that 7 days after the order date. That alone is no problem, but both fields are DATETIME and calculations with ADD_DATE include also the time.

This is the part where the date is calculated:

```
(kv.kaufdatum < '$abrechlimit' and kn.stornodatum > add_date(kv.kaufdatum, interval 7 day))
```

How can i tell to ignore the time?

Answer (score 0):

use date function properly  for example below query will returns 7days back date

```
 select   DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

it returns '2018-07-16'

below will returns

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-06-15", INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

'2017-06-08'

so you need for after 7days in you where clause

```
   date(kn.stornodatum) > DATE_ADD(kv.kaufdatum, interval 7 day)
```

Comment: This only works when i always have to go from today. But i have dates from the whole last month.

Comment: @WilliWuff those are example to get date function, i mentioned last your case "date(kn.stornodatum) > DATE_ADD(kv.kaufdatum, interval  7 day)"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
date(kn.stornodatum) > date_add(date(kv.kaufdatum), interval 7 day);
```

Comment: That's it! Didn't know that i can combine with DATE in that way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help :)